# how we create a menu list showing categories and subcategories using php

Tags: php

```
<ul class="navdrop">
    <li>category
       <ul>
         <li>subcategory
              <ul>
         <li>subcategory</li>
       </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

how we creat a loop to show catgeory and sub category in structure using php data

if tried while loop to print the main catgeory

```
<li><a class="shopdrop"><?php echo stripslashes($catParent_result['Category_Name']); ?></a></li>
```

Comment: It would be useful to post the data that you have for the menu - presumably a nested array?

Comment: but it has to create subcategory menu automatically depend on how many we add

Comment: He meant, what is the format of your data? The solution will not be the same if you use nested arrays or strings.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [Category_ID] => 2
    [1] => Accessories
    [Category_Name] => Accessories
    [2] => 
    [Category_Description] => 
    [3] => images_CMS/categories/2/1435073205_2_main.jpg
    [Category_Image] => images_CMS/categories/2/1435073205_2_main.jpg
    [4] => images_CMS/categories/2/1435073205_2_thumb.jpg
    [Category_Thumb] => images_CMS/categories/2/1435073205_2_thumb.jpg

)

Comment: That's the array corresponding to the data of a unique category right? How do you access all the categories' data to loop over?
Is it like this : array(<dataCategory1>, <dataCategory2>...)?
How do you identify a subcategory? Please provide some code in your question indicating the input of the function you're writing.

Comment: i dont know how i loop through sub categories

Comment: SELECT * from categories where Category_Parent = 0 AND Category_Active = 'Yes' show parent category it show all main category then i need to write a loop to check the same for subcategory

Answer (score 0):

Using a nested array, you can simply write a recursive function that generates an html list:

```
<?php
// the example input data
$example = array(
    "menu1" => "a",
    "menu2" => "b",
    "menu3" => array(
        "submenu3.1" => "c",
        "submenu3.2" => "d"
    ),
    "menu4" => array(
        "submenu4.1" => array ( "subsubmenu4.1.1" => "e"),
    ),
);

//
// print an ul menu out of a given (nested) array
//
function ulmenu($arr, $level=0)
{
    if (empty($arr) || !is_array($arr) || sizeof($arr)<1) return;
    // using a prefix is optional, for the purpose of learning,
    // it makes the output more readable
    $spaceprefix = str_repeat(" ", $level*4);
    echo "\n${spaceprefix}<ul>\n";
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "${spaceprefix}  <li>${key}";
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            // recursive call of limenu
            ulmenu($value, $level+1);
        }
        else
        {
            echo " : ${value}";
        }
        echo "</li>\n";
    }
    echo "${spaceprefix}</ul>";
}

ulmenu($example);

?>
```

This will generate

```
<ul>
  <li>menu1 : a</li>
  <li>menu2 : b</li>
  <li>menu3
    <ul>
      <li>submenu3.1 : c</li>
      <li>submenu3.2 : d</li>
    </ul></li>
  <li>menu4
    <ul>
      <li>submenu4.1
        <ul>
          <li>subsubmenu4.1.1 : e</li>
        </ul></li>
    </ul></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks , the all the main category and subcategory are stored in single table and different them using a field categoryparent if category parent is 0 then it is main category so how i create a nested array from single table

Comment: Please edit your questions and add the input array copy- n pasteable.